# Wiring a ceiling fan

Tags: wiring

I need help in wiring a new ceiling fan, no electrical feed. We wired it to our light switch which apparently controls our bottom outlet. When we did this the fan did not work when we flip the switch, unless we plug something into the bottom outlet and turned it on. How can we fix this problem?

Comment: Can you elaborate on, "no electrical feed" ? You mean there was no existing box in the ceiling?

Comment: Describe what wires were in the switch box, and how did you wire the new fan switch? Did you change the wiring in the receptacle? I bet it was a switch loop and you did not re-wire the receptacle box to create a constant feed.

Comment: Yes, there was no existing box in the ceiling. No did change the wiring in the receptacle switch. Fed the romex to the switch attach the black (hot) to the black. attach white wire to white wire with wire nut. How do you create a constant feed?

Comment: 14/2 romex used and also in the existing switch

Comment: Can you re-run the wiring between the receptacle and the switch, or remove the existing cable from the fan to the switch and replace it with a cable run from the fan to the receptacle?

Answer (score 1):

Your bedroom outlets have been wired to the receptacles in the traditional "switched outlet" configuration. On your receptacles there are brass bridge tabs creating the circuit between the two receptacle plugs, the electrician has removed this bridge and wired the top receptacle to a "hot" wire and the bottom to the "switched hot" from the light switch. The bottom of the light switch should have a constant "hot" wire on it. You will need to purchased a single gang two switch light switch and replace the existing single gang light switch with the dual. Jumper the existing incoming hot wire to the two new switches. One switch will continue to switch your outlets and the new switch will control the fan. You will need to run a wire to the ceiling fixture to power the fan if no current wiring exists. Use a licensed electrician if you are not capable of performing these changes.